# Is TF Build 2013 compatible with TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2013

I have a project hosted on a TFS 2012, and a build controller/agent (also 2012) on another computer. This configuration works fine.

I'd like to upgrade my build controller/agent to 2013 (so I can work on Windows 8.1 applications), while keeping TFS 2012 on the other computer to host my projects. Would the 2 be compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever attempt this? I'm in the same situation and I'm wondering what your results were. I notice you never accepted an answer for this question, so I'm curious if you were successful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's compatible, your agent is just service windows, his role is to host your build workflow