# Build BizTalk 2013 R2 source controlled in TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, biztalk, tfsbuild, biztalk-2013r2

I'm hoping this isn't closed as a duplicate of [Is TF Build 2013 compatible with TFS 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733251/is-tf-build-2013-compatible-with-tfs-2012) because the question is almost two years old, the only answer it got was of low quality and the answer was not accepted.

My company is currently running an on-premises TFS 2012 Application Tier with a TFS 2012 Build Agent, which builds BizTalk 2013 projects. We're considering an upgrade to BizTalk 2013 R2, but we know that BizTalk 2013 R2 doesn't build in VS 2012.

We know we will eventually have to upgrade our TFS installation, but for now we don't have the resources and we're looking for a short-term solution. Our idea was to investigate upgrading only the Build Agent to the 2013 version (or potentially even just the Visual Studio installation on the Build Agent machine?) so that we don't have to expend the effort to upgrade both systems simultaneously.

Specifically, is it possible to build BizTalk 2013 R2 projects if the TFS Application Tier is still 2012?
More generally, is it possible to upgrade only the Build Agent to 2013 or higher if the TFS Application Tier is 2012?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as I don't use Biztalk, but I'd think installing VS2013 on the TFS2012 build server would resolve it.

Where I work we have TFS2012.4 and VS 2012.4 & VS2013.4 on the installed on the build server so that we can build newer project types and .net 4.5.2 stuff.

You could test by running a build agent/controller, either on your machine or in a Hyper-V VM if you have Win 8 or greater - just remember to "tag" the agent so it doesn't get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

TFS and Build of Biztalk are two separate thing, you don't need to upgrade TFS to upgrade Biztalk. If you install VS 2013 on build agent that will fix yr problem. In order to test I would recommend to have a new build server with VS2013 and Biztalk 2013 R2.

Comment: Incidentally, this is exactly what I've requested from my IT department for our proof of concept :) Thanks!